# parse the JSON response from a uri request with Ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

I want to get only names (name1, name2) from this json output with ansible

```
{
   "query":{
      "app":"app1",
      "env":"app2",
      "type":"app3"
   },
   "result":[
      {
         "name":"name1",
         "yyy":"xxxxxxx",
         "yyy":[
            "xxx"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"name2",
         "yyy":"xxxxxxx",
         "yyy":[
            "xxx"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my task.yml (url/json return the json output)

```
uri:

  url: "url/json"
  method: GET
  force: yes
  return_content: yes
  status_code:
    - 200
    - 500
register: registered_variable
```

So how can I parse this json to get the names. I registered the json output in `registered_variable`.

Comment: So how can I parse* this json to get the names?, i registred the json output in registered_variable

Comment: Please check http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter

Comment: yes I did it but I had always this error: "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Comment: Providing [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a good way to get complete and rapid answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't documented in the uri module's docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/uri_module.html

But when valid json is returned, it is unmarshalled into the `json` key of the result.

I see you already register, so you should be able to access the filds you want as: `registered_variable.json.result[0].name` and `registered_variable.json.result[1].name`, I'm not sure if you always expect two elements in that array or not, so handling that is up to you.

Comment: Do you have a hint how to iterate over the results, if there is an unknown amount of structures?

Comment: I hadthis "registered_variable.json.result[0].name": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Comment: Is `registered_variable` actually what you have after `register: `? And are you using it after that task?